# Find all non-zero cells in a given range and list their addresses in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a gigantic table in excel(720x720) in which I want to find non-zero values. when the value is found I would like to get the first two cells of this row on a new sheet on two columns, the cell in question on a third and the first two cells in the columns of the cell I'm looking for on two other columns.

For example if my values are in E26 R89 and Z9 on sheet 1 I would like to get a table on sheet 2 that would look like this:

```
      A      B      C     D     E
1    A26    B26    E26    E1    E2   
2    A89    B89    R89    R1    R2
3    A9     B9     Z9     Z1    Z2
```

Here is what I've tried so far (please bear in mind that you are talking to a beginner)

```
Sub tests_selection()
    Dim r As Worksheet
    Dim c As Workbook, f As Worksheet
    Set c = Workbooks("classeur1")
    Set f = c.Worksheets("feuil1")

    Dim a(5200)
    Dim b

    b = 0

    Range("A1:AAU723").Select
    For i = 4 To 720
        For j = 4 To 723
            If f.Cells(i, j).Value <> 0 Then
            a(b) = f.Cells(i, j).Adress
            b = b + 1
            End If

        Next j
    Next i

    Set r = c.Worksheets("result")

    For i = 0 To b
        r.Cells(i, 1).Value = a(i)
    Next i    
End Sub
```

Table example
[image: Table example]

Result example
[image: Result example]

Comment: What have you tried so far? You will get more help if you provide what you have tried so far and how it didn't work

Comment: You need to loop through each cell of the 720x720 range, test if the cell is non-zero if yes remember the address of the cell in a `collection` and after that loop you will need another loop to output the collection to the sheet2. Try this and when you got stuck or errors come back with your code and ask a question to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should use meaningful variable names instead of 1 character only. This makes your code much more understandable and readable and therefore results in less bugs.

Also use `Option Explicit` to force proper variable declaring.

```
Option Explicit

Sub tests_selection()
    Dim SrcWs As Worksheet
    Set SrcWs = Worksheets("feuil1") 'source worksheet

    Dim ResultWs As Worksheet
    Set ResultWs = Worksheets("result") 'result worksheet

    Dim rRow As Long
    rRow = 2 'start row in result sheet

    Dim iCell As Range
    For Each iCell In SrcWs.Range("C4:AN40") '<-- make sure to adjust the range to the data only! so header rows are not included
        If iCell.Value <> 0 Then
            ResultWs.Cells(rRow, 1).Value = SrcWs.Cells(iCell.Row, 1).Value
            ResultWs.Cells(rRow, 2).Value = SrcWs.Cells(iCell.Row, 2).Value
            ResultWs.Cells(rRow, 3).Value = iCell.Value
            ResultWs.Cells(rRow, 4).Value = SrcWs.Cells(1, iCell.Column).Value
            ResultWs.Cells(rRow, 5).Value = SrcWs.Cells(2, iCell.Column).Value

            rRow = rRow + 1
        End If
    Next iCell
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much but now that i have the adresses how do i go from let's say AB25 to AB1 or A25

Comment: I don't understand why you would do that? What is the rule for that?

Comment: Well, if you look at my example at the top I'm only able to get the C column so far and i would like to get the 4 other columns as well.

Comment: Well, I see no rule how they are sorted in that example, they just look mixed up. You will need to explain which data has to be sorted in which column and why.

Comment: If the value in cell E26 is different from 0 i want the first two cell on this row and the first two cells on the column. Then in a new sheet the first two column will get the first two cells that have the same row , fallow by my cell value (E26) in the third column and finally the first two cells of the same column.
Thus :
A26    B26    E26    E1    E2

Comment: Well I don't understand *anything* at all of what you wrote in that comment. You need to explain **why**. Why is "E26" in cell C1? Why this order `A26    B26    E26    E1    E2`? We need a rule how this should be sorted?

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your help this far and I'll do my best to explain what i'm looking for.
I have a table where the first two columns are coordinate of the first point the first two line are the coordinate of the second point the values I have are the difference of potential between these two points.
Once i found a value different from 0 i need the coordinate of the first point on the first two columns, the difference of potential in the third column and then the coordinate of the second point in the two last columns.

Comment: @DjallelEddineBouakaz can you edit your original question and add a screenshot of the data? And also a screenshot of the final table how it would look like after the macro? I think we are totally up the wrong tree already. I think we need a totally other approach to achieve that.

Comment: I didn't do a full result example but i think it'll be clearer now.

Comment: much more clear now. And completely different approach: see my edit. Just make sure you adjust the range `SrcWs.Range("C4:AN40")` to your data only so it starts at C4 so headers and left 2 columns are not in the range.

Comment: THANK YOU, thank you so much for your patience.
I can not thank you enough.

Comment: @DjallelEddineBouakaz Well, I'm always up for some science :) Knowing that these values are "the difference of potentials" and the screeshots really helped a lot to understand. Please mark this answer as solved then.